# Detect incoming NotificationCenter notification on iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

Is there an API that allows me to know when NotificationCenter will pop a notification on the top of the screen while my app is running (for example for an incoming Message or email)?

It causes a big performance glitch to my game so I'd like to pause it and unpause once the notification has disappeared. If there is no event to listen to I can only think of monitoring FPS and pausing for a few seconds if it drops below a threshold. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: My answer is only for popup notifications, not for the ones that scroll on to the top of the screen. Sorry :(

---

In your app delegate, the method

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

will be called.

And then

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

when it's time to start up again.